# A function that return the values of all attributes

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to give an instance of object to a function and the function return the value of all attributes for this instance ?? the function should work for any class

Comment: Note that such a code is usually just a workaround for bad architecture. Although it is often useful for debugging or testing.

Comment: What @Sulthan said.  If this code and the answers to your other questions are used beyond debugging or pure academic curiosity, you are heading down a path that will produce a very difficult, very fragile, codebase.   Objective-C was simply not designed for this level of introspection based programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
unsigned int numberOfAttributs;
objc_property_t *attributes = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &numberOfAttributes);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfAttributes; i++) {

    objc_property_t attribute = attributes[i];  
    NSString *attributeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: property_getName(attribute)];
    NSLog(@"%@", attributeName);
    id attributeValue = [obj valueForKey:attributeName];
    NSLog(@"%@", attributeValue);
}
```

Comment: for value, you could try:- [obj valueForKey:@"property_getName(attribute)"]; Try it and then let me know the success

Comment: you can add a check and check for type of variable!

Comment: @bbum `valueForKey` will always return an object, even if it's a `NSValue`.

Comment: I have fixed the types to `unsigned` and the first parameter of `class_copyPropertyList`.

Comment: property_getName return a 'const char *' not an NSString, so this answer will crash ...

Comment: Note that this is going to barf on properties that return structs and it is also going to miss any setter/getter pairs that are not declared as @property.